# Roulette Wheel Selection in genetic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am confusing the roulette wheel selection in genetic algorithm. The algorithm is shown as following

```
for i=1 to N
 x=random[0,1];
 k=1;
 while k<N&&x>cusum
   k=k+1
 end
tmp_P[i]=P[k];
end
```

Is it correct? I am confusing the while condition

**First way:**

```
 while k<N&&x>cusum
   k=k+1
 end
 tmp_P[i]=P[k];
```

**Or second way**

```
 while k<N&&x>cusum
   k=k+1;     
   tmp_P[i]=P[k];
end
```

Which is correct? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is correct.

You go through your cumsum array until you find the one bigger than your random number and select that individual.

However, I would expect that your cusum variable should be an array and you would use:

```
 while k<N && x>cusum[k]
```